# After SQL Server 2008 upgrade, query with UNION runs very slowly

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000, performance

We migrated from SQL Server 2000 to 2008 and a query for some users (in certain database roles) runs very slowly when we use UNION operator. I tried it with UNION ALL

The query is like below

```
SELECT  'PONumber'= '','POId'=''

UNION 

SELECT DISTINCT 
                'PONumber'=PONumber, 
                'POId'=RTRIM(CONVERT(varchar(32),po.POId) )
FROM  PurchaseOrder po JOIN  ... JOIN ..... JOIN ...................
```

If I just remove the first part (and UNION) and run the second query the results are returned immediately.

Any suggestions?

Comment: how was the same query executing before the update? I would check execution plan and rebuild affected indices just in case.

Comment: You'll need to look at the execution plans. Looks like you are not schema qualifying your objects (e.g. `dbo.PurchaseOrder` so I think that might explain why different users get different plans)

Comment: Not sure whether it is helpful to note that one of the joined table uses the sysusers and sysmembers system tables uid column as we are using SQL Server in-built security across the database

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how it would have reacted in SQL 2000, but using `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` is going to cause a sort operation when the results of the two queries are merged (to get rid of duplicates). That can be a significant amount of processing, depending on the size of your result set.

Also, tempdb usage change pretty dramatically between SQL 2000 and SQL 2008. A sort operation is likely to use tempdb, so you should check the media for your tempdb and make sure that it has plenty of space, etc.

Comment: Yes. tempdb is using only 640 MB now and  have 400 MB left. Not sure whether it is helpful to note that one of the joined table uses the sysusers and sysmembers system tables uid column as we are using SQL Server in-built security across the database

Comment: I would try testing the code on another server with more `tempdb` space and see if that helps.